# User Interface for filtering objects in Python

Tags: python, api, design-patterns

In my application I have a Job class as defined/outlined below. Instance of this job class represents a particular Job run. Job can have multiple checkpoints and each checkpoint can have multiple commands.

```
Job
 - JobName
 - [JobCheckpoint]
 - StartTime
 - EndTime
 - Status
 - ...

JobCheckpoint
 - JobCheckpointName
 - [JobCommand]
 - StartTime
 - EndTime
 - Status
 - ...

JobCommand
 - JobCommandName
 - [Command]
 - StartTime
 - EndTime
 - Status 
 - ...
```

At any given day there are like 100k different jobs that runs. Job information is persisted in File System. I want to design a user interface in Python for querying these job objects. For example users should be able to query

1. All jobs that ran between x and y interval.
2. All jobs that run command x.
3. All jobs in failed state.
4. All jobs in failed and terminated state.
5. All checkpoints/commands of a particular job.
6. And many more...

To solve this, I was thinking of providing following method in user interface.

```
 get_jobs(Filter)
```

I am not sure how can I design this Filter class in Python

1. to support all such sort of queries on Job object.
2. and to keep usage of API simple/intuitive for user.

Leads here is really appreciated.

Comment: A `dict` consists of keys and values. If the values are `Job`s, what should be the keys? If you don't know, maybe a `list` would be better.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I updated the qn. Question is basically returning a List<Dict> a correct design or returning List<DomainObject> is a correct design?

Comment: Because the items you return have a defined set of properties (as listed by you, e.g. a job has a name, start time, ...) a specific domain object is usually the better option. Is the whole data stored in memory as Python objects or in some kind of database?

Comment: In file system and I read it from filesystem and construct a domain object

Comment: Is it planned to allow restriction of output to some attributes (e.g. list only start time of all jobs that run command x)? If so, a dictionary (or maybe a `collections.namedtuple()` would be more efficient. Otherwise, if the complete information about the object should be given anyway, a domain object would be right. E.g. a returned job object could then provide methods to load its checkpoints on demand to be more efficient. A dict couldn't do that.

Comment: makes sense, thanks. Any suggestion on designing filter class?

Comment: Most flexible way would be a simple method `filter(domainObject)` which returns a boolean for each domainObject if it should be kept or not. Other way could be a whole set of filter classes (e.g. one for compare against start date, one against end date, one for job state), some taking two filters for logical combination (and, or) to build a filter tree which could then be optimized before applying (if filter A and B must match, apply the one first which reduces the possible results more).

Comment: But how users will call this? Is Filter a user exposed method/API? 

How will a call look like for all jobs in failed state?

Comment: It depends on how much complexity you want to provide to the users. One way can be to create a query language which is then parsed and a described filter tree is created from it. Simpler approach can be a form with some entries (start date before, after; job state, ...). In this case, the filter class can be simpler as well.

Comment: ok goal here is to keep interface to a system simple for user and it should not be rigid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are partially subjective questions. But I'll have a go at answering some of them to the best of my current knowledge and the information available in the question posed.

*How Filter class will look like?*

That could depend for instance on the storage mechanism. Is it stored in-memory as a bunch of Python objects or is it first taken out of an SQL database or perhaps a NoSQL database.

If it's taken from an SQL database you can take advantage of the filtering mechanism of SQL. It's after all a (Structured) Query Language.

In that case your Filter class would be like a translator of field values to a bunch of SQL operators/conditions.

If it's a bunch of Python objects without some database mechanism to use for querying your data then you might need to think of your own query/filter methods.

A Filter class might be using a Condition class and an Operator class. Maybe you have an Operator class as an abstract class and have 'glue' operators to glue conditions together (AND/OR). And another kind of operators to compare a property of a domain object with a value.

For the latter, even if you are not designing a 'filter language' for it, you could get some inspiration from an API querying format, specified here for Flask-Restless: https://flask-restless.readthedocs.io/en/stable/searchformat.html#query-format

Surely if you are designing a query interface to e.g. a REST API, Flask-Restless's query-format could give you some inspiration of how to tackle the querying.

*Is returning List of domain objects correct or should I return list of dict?*

Returning a list of domain objects has the advantage of being able to use inheritance. That's at least one possible advantage.

A rough sketch of certain classes:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from typing import List

class DomainObjectOperatorGlue(metaclass=ABCMeta):    
    @abstractmethod
    def operate(self, haystack: List['DomainObject'], criteria: 
        List['DomainObject']) -> List['DomainObject']:
        pass

class DomainObjectFieldGlueOperator(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def operate(self, conditions: List[bool]) -> bool:
        pass

class DomainObjectFieldGlueOperatorAnd(DomainObjectFieldGlueOperator):
    def operate(self, conditions: List[bool]) -> bool:
        # If all conditions are True then return True here,
        # otherwise return False.
        # (...)
        pass

class DomainObjectFieldGlueOperatorOr(DomainObjectFieldGlueOperator):
    def operate(self, conditions: List[bool]) -> bool:
        # If only one (or more) of the conditions are True then return True
        # otherwise, if none are True, return False.
        # (...)
        pass


class DomainObjectOperatorAnd(DomainObjectOperatorGlue):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def operate(self, haystack: 'JobsCollection', criteria: 
List['DomainObject']) -> List['DomainObject']:
        """
        Returns list of haystackelements or empty list.
        Includes haystackelement if all (search) 'criteria' elements 
(DomainObjects) are met for haystackelement (DomainObject).
        """
        result = []
        for haystackelement in haystack.jobs:
            # AND operator wants all criteria to be True for haystackelement (Job)
        # to be included in returned search results.
        criteria_all_true_for_haystackelement = True
        for criterium in criteria:
            if haystackelement.excludes(criterium):
                criteria_all_true_for_haystackelement = False
                break
        if criteria_all_true_for_haystackelement:
            result.append(haystackelement)
    return result

class DomainObjectOperatorOr(DomainObjectOperatorGlue):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

def operate(self, haystack: List['DomainObject'], criteria: List['DomainObject']) -> List['DomainObject']:
    """
    Returns list of haystackelements or empty list.
    Includes haystackelement if all (search) 'criteria' elements (DomainObjects) are met for haystackelement (DomainObject).
    """
    result = []
    for haystackelement in haystack:
        # OR operator wants at least ONE criterium to be True for haystackelement
        # to be included in returned search results.
        at_least_one_criterium_true_for_haystackelement = False
        for criterium in criteria:
            if haystackelement.matches(criterium):
                at_least_one_criterium_true_for_haystackelement = True
                break
        if at_least_one_criterium_true_for_haystackelement:
            result.append(haystackelement)
    return result

class DomainObjectFilter(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, criteria: List['DomainObject'], criteria_glue: 
DomainObjectOperatorGlue):
        self.criteria = criteria
        self.criteria_glue = criteria_glue

    @abstractmethod
    def apply(self, haystack: 'JobsCollection') -> List['DomainObject']:
        """
       Applies filter to given 'haystack' (list of jobs with sub-objects in there);
    returns filtered list of DomainObjects or empty list if none found
    according to criteria (and criteria glue).
        """
        return self.criteria_glue.operate(haystack, self.criteria)

class DomainObject(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def matches(self, domain_object: 'DomainObject') -> bool:
        """ Returns True if this DomainObject matches specified DomainObject,
    False otherwise.
     """
    pass

def excludes(self, domain_object: 'DomainObject') -> bool:
    """
    Convenience method; the inverse of includes-method.
    """
    return not self.matches(domain_object)


class Job(DomainObject):
    def __init__(self, name, start, end, status, job_checkpoints: 
List['JobCheckpoint']):
        self.name = name
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.status = status
        self.job_checkpoints = job_checkpoints

    def matches(self, domain_object: 'DomainObject', field_glue: 
DomainObjectFieldGlueOperator) -> bool:
        """
        Returns True if this DomainObject includes specified DomainObject,
     False otherwise.
         """
        if domain_object is Job:
            # See if specified fields in search criteria (domain_object/Job) matches this job.
            # Determine here which fields user did not leave empty,
            # and guess for sensible search criteria.
            # Return True if it's  a match, False otherwise.
            condition_results = []
            if domain_object.name != None:
                condition_results.append(domain_object.name in self.name)
            if domain_object.start != None or domain_object.end != None:
                if domain_object.start == None:
                    # ...Use broadest start time for criteria here...
                    # time_range_condition = ...
                    condition_results.append(time_range_condition)                 
                elif domain_object.end == None:
                    # ...Use broadest end time for criteria here...
                    # time_range_condition = ...
                    condition_results.append(time_range_condition)                 
                else:
                    # Both start and end time specified; use specified time range.
                # time_range_condition = ...
                condition_results.append(time_range_condition)
            # Then evaluate condition_results;
            # e.g. return True if all condition_results are True here,
            # false otherwise depending on implementation of field_glue class:
            return field_glue.operate(condition_results)
    elif domain_object is JobCheckpoint:
        # Determine here which fields user did not leave empty,
        # and guess for sensible search criteria.
        # Return True if it's  a match, False otherwise.
        # First establish if parent of JobCheckpoint is 'self' (this job)
        # if so, then check if search criteria for JobCheckpoint match,
        # glue fields with something like:
        return field_glue.operate(condition_results)
    elif domain_object is JobCommand:
        # (...)
        if domain_object.parent_job == self:
            # see if conditions pan out
            return field_glue.operate(condition_results)

class JobCheckpoint(DomainObject):
    def __init__(self, name, start, end, status, job_commands: List['JobCommand'], parent_job: Job):
       self.name = name
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.status = status
       self.job_commands = job_commands
        # For easier reference;
        # e.g. when search criteria matches this JobCheckpoint
        # then Job associated to it can be found
        # more easily.
        self.parent_job = parent_job

class JobCommand(DomainObject):
    def __init__(self, name, start, end, status, parent_checkpoint: JobCheckpoint, parent_job: Job):
        self.name = name
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.status = status
        # For easier reference;
        # e.g. when search criteria matches this JobCommand
        # then Job or JobCheckpoint associated to it can be found
        # more easily.
        self.parent_checkpoint = parent_checkpoint
        self.parent_job = parent_job

class JobsCollection(DomainObject):
    def __init__(self, jobs: List['Job']):
         self.jobs = jobs

    def get_jobs(self, filter: DomainObjectFilter) -> List[Job]:
        return filter.apply(self)

    def get_commands(self, job: Job) -> List[JobCommand]:
        """
        Returns all commands for specified job (search criteria).
        """
        result = []
        for some_job in self.jobs:
            if job.matches(some_job):
                for job_checkpoint in job.job_checkpoints:
                    result.extend(job_checkpoint.job_commands)
         return result

    def get_checkpoints(self, job: Job) -> List[JobCheckpoint]:
        """
        Returns all checkpoints for specified job (search criteria).
        """
        result = []
        for some_job in self.jobs:
            if job.matches(some_job):
                result.extend(job.job_checkpoints)
        return result
```

Comment: Storage is a file system.

Comment: I guess this makes sense "A Filter class might be using a Condition class and an Operator class. Maybe you have an Operator class as an abstract class and have 'glue' operators to glue conditions together (AND/OR). And another kind of operators to compare a property of a domain object with a value." Any rough class skeleton for this?

Comment: I've added some rough skeleton classes for this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed class skeleton. This makes sense to me.

Comment: If you would have given its sample usage example then it would have been easy to track the code.